# How to get user by id in discordjs 12?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

In the previous version of api I can do that with :

```js
client.fetchUser('myid');
```

but from the v12 that not work anymore.

So what is the alternatives ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For discordjs 12 you should use `client.users.fetch(myId)` instead fetchUser.

See in documentation: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#fetch

Comment: but the documentation has been move ?
is not here : https://discord.js.org/ usualy ?

Comment: I find with link (to guide) in discord.js.org, on this page: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/general/updating

Comment: Ok :o it's really official so ^^